HDDs keep restarting, but only on Windows
I bought a new HDD and I copied all files from the old one to the new. I used Ubuntu, the copying took about 12 hours. I did it twice. No problems.
But now I use this new HDD with WIN10 and every time I do something slightly more extensive (like torrents, copying) than watching VLC, I hear that BZIGT, HDD turns off, then spins up again. The reason why I bought new HDD was because I thought old one was failing, but this is happening with new one too.
There was a half year period when this did not happen, but as of this month I again cannot use HDD normally. Is PSU failing? But then again - why not while running Ubuntu with TWO HDDs simultaneously?

"I did it twice" why?... "BZIGT" what is this? Did the disk spin down at all before/during/after the copy? Does the disk only spin down during idle periods?

What does event viewer say? Does the computer crash or anything go wrong? Do the file copies fail? A noise and a drive spinning down isn't very specific or clear indication of any actual problem.

I did it twice because I formatted disk after first copy (doesnt matter :D), the sounds i meant is of HDD turning off. Then it starts again, spins up, and I can access it again.
Copying did not fail at all with Ubuntu.

Most likely its your windows settings

Open Settings
Select Power & Sleep
Click on Additional Power Settings
One option will be selected, - Click on Change Plan Settings on it
Change Advance Power Settings
Change the Turn off hard disk after...


